# How to open an EditText View when clicking on an Action Bar Menu Options Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app (in Java) where the Action bar has an Options Menu of items/options (onCreateOptionsMenu resulting in the three vertical dots on the top right of the screen), so that when the user clicks on the three vertical dots, the menu expands showing the list of items/options. I want one of these items, when clicked, to open up an EditText view to enable the user to enter some text. I've spent quite some time researching this but I've not been able to find how it's done. Can somebody please provide the outline of how to achieve this or perhaps point me to an example.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `dialog_layout.xml` file and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:hint="@string/about_routine_dialog_image"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:textColor="#3C3B3B"
    android:inputType="number"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDialogSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then run below function calling `showDialog` when user click on that particular menu-item:

```
public void showDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

    final EditText editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog);
    Button buttonDialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonDialogSubmit);
    buttonDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString(); //your text from editText
            dialog.dismiss();
            //do your work here
        }
    });
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```